# chmod not working in a non super user

Tags: 14.04, files, chmod, chown

I have created a file named `*.txt` in `/home` using following command:

> sudo nano *.txt

Then I have changed owner of `*.txt` to a `user` that I've created:

> sudo useradd -c "ABC"
>
> sudo chown ABC *.txt

I login to `ABC` by typing:

> sudo login ABC

I tried to change permission of the file:

> sudo chmod 777 *.txt

This is the result:

`ABC is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

Permissions have successfully changed when running `chmod` from the original user: `batman`.

How can I change the permissions of `*.txt` from the new owner?

[image: This is inside <code>ABC</code> user]

Comment: 1. please copy & paste output instead of screenshots; 2. to use `sudo` in Ubuntu you need to be in the `sudo` group (or you need to be in the sudoers file like the error suggests); 3. you're getting "no such file or directory" because you forgot to `cd` to the right directory

Comment: What's the right directory? It should be in ABC user, right?

Comment: No, you created the files in your home directory, they can't be in ABC's home directory: `cd ~batman; chmod 744 *.txt` -- but you may get errors depending on the directory permissions

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu so I don't get it 100% the group idea. Sorry.

Comment: But the `ABC` user is the new owner of this file. Right? How can I fix it ?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I didn't understand, plz could you explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I need to do is to be in the directory which contains the file.
Solution:

> cd home
>
> chmod 777 *.txt

That's all.
But be aware to change the name of the file because the `*` in `*.txt` isn't a valid name.

Answer (score 0):

If you step through your commands and the output these are your problems.

The file `*.txt` is located in batman's home directory.

1. Switch to ABC user: `sudo login ABC`.
   You just made ABC and it doesn't have a home directory so you got thrown into the root directory
2. You try `chmod 777 *.txt`, but you are in the root dir and the file is not there.
3. You exit back into batman and try to chmod the file, but now it belongs to ABC and batman can't change it.

To Solve:

login as batman

```
su ABC

cd /home/batman

chown 777 *.txt
```

Comment: I have some questions: 1. How can I make a home directory for `ABC`.                 2. When I make a `chmod`, It's obligatory that I must go to the file location?  3.When I tried to `chmod` in the `batman` it's successfully completed and there's no problem with that!! Why? Thanks.